# Open a csv file, delete columns containing a word in their name, save in a new csv Pandas, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, scikit-learn

I have a csv file. In this file there are a lot of columns named as:

value_number, species_name, color_name, unnamed:1 etc...

How can I implement a python script using pandas that open a csv file, search in its columns that have the word unnamed and then delete them and save the cleaned csv as a new csv with an updated name.

Here is the script:

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd



path= "/home/CaptainSnake/Desktop/Test_class/class_data"

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "Classification_testData_*.csv"))
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files)
df_merged   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=False, sort=False)
df_merged.columns

df_merged.columns.str.match('Unnamed')
df_merged.loc[:, ~df_merged.columns.str.match('Unnamed')]
df_merged.to_csv( "Classification_testData_cleaned.csv")
```

This script in particular, does the merging of all csv with a particular name...then It should clear the new csv from unnamed: etc..

Comment: Please provide a sample of the input csv, along with the desired output. Also please add any attempts you have made to resolve this.

Comment: @Rishin sorry..I updated the question...before I deleted for mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove all the columns that starts with 'Unnamed':

```
filtered_cols = [i for i in df.columns if not i.startswith("Unnamed")]
df[filtered_cols].to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: dear @Rishin very gentle, and good answer. Just a little doubt in addition. And if I want delete two types? So Unnamed and columns without name?? How could I do?

Comment: @TforV Use this filtered_cols = [i for i in df.columns if not i.startswith("Unnamed") and len(i)>0]. This will remove empty column names as well